# How to remove Bradford Persistent Agent in Catalina

Tags: mac, uninstall, macos-catalina, daemon, launch-agent

How do you you remove the Bradford Persistent Agent from a Mac running macOS Catalina?

The main issue is that the given `/Library/Application Support/Bradford Networks/Persistent Agent/Uninstall.app` application is 32-bit, which my current OS cannot run.

Desired outcomes:

1. No icon in the system toolbar.
2. No Bradford-related daemons/tasks launched on start-up.
3. No more `Application Support/Bradford Networks` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the [existing tutorials](https://www.bates.edu/helpdesk/2017/01/05/how-do-i-uninstall-the-bradford-campus-manager-bradford-persistent-agent-from-my-computer/) I could find relied on the Uninstaller program located in `/Library/Application Support/Bradford Networks/Persistent Agent/Uninstall.app`. Unfortunately, this is a 32-bit app and cannot run on Catalina, which can only run 64-bit (I tried running the executable inside and the error is:

```
bad CPU type in executable: /Library/Application Support/Bradford Networks/Persistent Agent/Uninstall.app/Contents/MacOS/Uninstall
```

Within the application contents folder, however, is `Resources/Scripts/Uninstall.sh` (contents posted below). I cannot verify whether this does everything that the `.app` container does, but I ran it (`sudo ./Uninstall.sh`) and it appears that everything was successfully removed: no more launch daemons, no more `Bradford Networks` directory.

**Uninstall.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/sh
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bradfordnetworks.agent.plist 2>/dev/null >/dev/null 
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.bradfordnetworks.bndaemon.plist expirationTime -string "" 
/Library/Application\ Support/Bradford\ Networks/Persistent\ Agent/LoginItemTiger remove /Library/Application\ Support/Bradford\ Networks/Persistent\ Agent/CSA.app 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bradfordnetworks.* 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.bradfordnetworks.* 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
rm -r "/Library/Application Support/Bradford Networks" 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
rm -r "/Library/Receipts/Bradford Persistent Agent.pkg" 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
rm -r "/Library/Receipts/Aruba Persistent Agent.pkg" 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
rm -r "/Library/Receipts/bradfordpersistentagentappsupport.pkg" 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
rm -r "/Library/Receipts/bradfordpersistentagentlaunchdaemons.pkg" 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
if [ -x /usr/sbin/pkgutil ]
then
    /usr/sbin/pkgutil --forget com.bradfordnetworks.PersistentAgent
    /usr/sbin/pkgutil --forget com.bradfordnetworks.bradfordPersistentAgent
fi
killall -9 CSA 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
exit 0;
```

Comment: Nice work dealing with a legacy headache like this!